# Generating elixir test folder & scaffolding

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Is it possible to generate the entire test folder and structure from mix or can it only be done when you first create the project? 
I need to recreate the entire test folder on an already existing project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mix` generates a very limited scaffold for the test folder:

```
* creating test
* creating test/test_helper.exs
* creating test/my_project_test.exs
```

that said, there are two files in a folder:

*test/test_helper.exs*

```rb
ExUnit.start()
```

*test/my_project_test.exs*

```rb
defmodule MyProjectTest do
  use ExUnit.Case
  doctest MyProject

  test "greets the world" do
    assert MyProject.hello() == :world
  end
end
```

That’s it. AFAIK, `mix` is unable to generate tests *according* to your code. It cannot [at the moment of writing this] scaffold a test based on some source file. I am also unaware of any 3<sup>rd</sup> party package that could help here.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure what mix creates vs what is created when you run phoenix scaffolding. is it possible to run that on an already created project though? ie. mix new kv --module KV but just the base test folders or would you just do it manually?